# Set characters count per line in Delphi code

Tags: delphi

I do code format with Ctrl+D which makes code lines shorter. I was expecting I can adjust line width with right margin:

[image]

But this not helped. How to adjust code line width?

Comment: Tools > Options > Language > Formatter > Delphi > Line breaks > Right margin

Comment: @BrakNicku that should be posted as an answer rather than a comment.